# Deleting a comment(s) in a discussion crash iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

SO site, haven't tested elsewhere

This only crashes when a comment is deleted from a discussion that has greater than 1 comment.

If my comment indexPath is 6,7,9,11 and I delete 7. It deletes properly. As soon as user taps on a different index, the app crashes and reloads same question minus the comment deleted. Repeat til all comments are deleted. It doesn't matter what order, it crashes.

Running:

iPhone 6+

iOS 8.3

Reputation 1,600+ (if that matters for privileges)

Comment: I've been meaning to report this for a while.  Deleting one comment is fine, doing a second blows away the app.  I think it is all sites that do this in any iOS version.